# PHP abstract properties

Tags: php, oop, abstract-class

Is there any way to define abstract class properties in PHP?

```
abstract class Foo_Abstract {
    abstract public $tablename;
}

class Foo extends Foo_Abstract {
    //Foo must 'implement' $property
    public $tablename = 'users';   
}
```

Answer (score 167, accepted):

There is no such thing as defining a property.

You can only declare properties because they are containers of data reserved in memory on initialization.

A function on the other hand can be declared (types, name, parameters) without being defined (function body missing) and thus, can be made abstract.

"Abstract" only indicates that something was declared but not defined and therefore before using it, you need to define it or it becomes useless.

Comment: There is no obvious reason the word 'abstract' could not be used on *static* properties - but with a slightly different meaning. For example it could indicate that a subclass has to provide a value for the property.

Comment: In TypeScript there are [abstract properties and accessors](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#abstract-properties-and-accessors). It is sad that in php it is impossible.

Answer (score 65):

No, there is no way to enforce that with the compiler, you'd have to use run-time checks (say, in the constructor) for the `$tablename` variable, e.g.:

```
class Foo_Abstract {
  public final function __construct(/*whatever*/) {
    if(!isset($this->tablename))
      throw new LogicException(get_class($this) . ' must have a $tablename');
  }
}
```

To enforce this for all derived classes of Foo_Abstract you would have to make Foo_Abstract's constructor `final`, preventing overriding.

You could declare an abstract getter instead:

```
abstract class Foo_Abstract {
  abstract public function get_tablename();
}

class Foo extends Foo_Abstract {
  protected $tablename = 'tablename';
  public function get_tablename() {
    return $this->tablename;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice feature, i like how you implement abstract properties.

Comment: This would require you to make the constructor final in the abstract base class.

Comment: @hakre: I'm not sure I understand you?

Comment: Some explanation: If you do the check inside the constructor and if it should be mandatory, you need to ensure that it gets executed on every instance instantiation. Therefore you need to prevent that it gets removed, e.g. by extending the class and replacing the constructor. The [final keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php) would you allow to do so.

Comment: I like the "abstract getter" solution. When you declare a function in a class abstract, you must declare the class itself abstract. This means the class is unusable unless extended and fully implemented. When extending that class, you must provide an implementation for the "getter" function. This means that you must also create a related property inside the extending class, because the function must have something to return. Following this pattern you get the same result as if you would by declaring an abstract property, it's also a clean and clear approach. That's how it's actually done.

Comment: Using an abstract getter also allows you to implement it by **generating** a value, as opposed to returning a constant value, when it makes sense to do so. An abstract property would not allow you to do so, especially a static property.

Comment: Yes. Abstract getter is the way to go. It does not enforce implementation details, e.g. you could name your property differently and return it in the getter, or as sayed generate, validate, or do whatever you like with it.

Answer (score 45):

Depending on the context of the property, if I want to force declaration of an abstract class property in an extended class, I like to use a constant with the `static` keyword for the property in the abstract object constructor or setter/getter methods. You can optionally use [`final`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php) to prevent the method from being overridden in extended classes.

Example: https://3v4l.org/WH5Xl

```php
abstract class AbstractFoo
{
    public $bar;

    final public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bar = static::BAR;
    }
}

class Foo extends AbstractFoo
{
    //const BAR = 'foobar'; //uncomment to prevent exception
}
```

```php
$foo = new Foo(); 
//Fatal Error: Undefined class constant 'BAR'
```

---

However, the extended class overrides the parent class properties and methods if redefined.
For example; if a property is declared as `protected` in the parent and redefined as `public` in the extended class, the resulting property is `public`. Otherwise, if the property is declared `private` in the parent it will remain `private` and not available to the extended class.

http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: Most elegant solution here

Answer (score 26):

As stated above, there is no such exact definition.
I, however, use this simple workaround to force the child class to define the "abstract" property:

```
abstract class Father 
{
  public $name;
  abstract protected function setName(); // now every child class must declare this 
                                      // function and thus declare the property

  public function __construct() 
  {
    $this->setName();
  }
}

class Son extends Father
{
  protected function setName()
  {
    $this->name = "son";
  }

  function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
  }
}
```

Comment: Elegant, but doesn't solve the issue for `static` properties.

Comment: I don't think you can have private for abstract methods.

Comment: @Phate01 as i understand it, in the comment itself it states `the only "safe" methods to have in a constructor are private and/or final ones`, isnt my workaround such a case? im using privates in it

Comment: You don't need the constructor in the child class (Son). The parent will be called automatically if you leave it out.

Comment: Great answer ! Note that maybe `abstract protected function setName();` is better.

Comment: @sboye yes you are right, abstract private methods are not allowed in php (i must have written this by heart). i have edited my answer

Comment: This looks nice, but it doesn't force a child class to actually set `$name`.  You could implement the `setName()` function without it actually setting `$name`.

Comment: I think that using `getName` instead of `$name` works better. `abstract class Father { abstract protected function getName(); public function foo(){ echo $this->getName();} }`

Answer (score 12):

The need for abstract properties can indicate design problems. While many of answers implement kind of [Template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) and it works, it always looks kind of strange.

Let's take a look at the original example:

```
abstract class Foo_Abstract {
    abstract public $tablename;
}

class Foo extends Foo_Abstract {
    //Foo must 'implement' $property
    public $tablename = 'users';   
}
```

To mark something `abstract` is to indicate it a must-have thing. Well, **a must-have value** (in this case) **is a required dependency, so it should be passed to the constructor during instantiation**:

```
class Table
{
    private $name;

    public function __construct(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function name(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Then if you actually want a more concrete named class you can inherit like so:

```
final class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('users');
    }
}
```

This can be useful if you use DI container and have to pass different tables for different objects.

Answer (score 9):

I've asked myself the same question today, and I'd like to add my two cents.

The reason we would like `abstract` properties is to make sure that subclasses define them and throw exceptions when they don't. In my specific case, I needed something that could work with `static`ally.

Ideally I would like something like this:

```
abstract class A {
    abstract protected static $prop;
}

class B extends A {
    protected static $prop = 'B prop'; // $prop defined, B loads successfully
}

class C extends A {
    // throws an exception when loading C for the first time because $prop
    // is not defined.
}
```

I ended up with this implementation

```
abstract class A
{
    // no $prop definition in A!

    public static final function getProp()
    {
        return static::$prop;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    protected static $prop = 'B prop';
}

class C extends A
{
}
```

As you can see, in `A` I don't define `$prop`, but I use it in a `static` getter. Therefore, the following code works

```
B::getProp();
// => 'B prop'

$b = new B();
$b->getProp();
// => 'B prop'
```

In `C`, on the other hand, I don't define `$prop`, so I get exceptions:

```
C::getProp();
// => Exception!

$c = new C();
$c->getProp();
// => Exception!
```

I must call the `getProp()` method to get the exception and I can't get it on class loading, but it is quite close to the desired behavior, at least in my case.

I define `getProp()` as `final` to avoid that some *smart guy* (aka myself in 6 months) is tempted to do

```
class D extends A {
    public static function getProp() {
        // really smart
    }
}

D::getProp();
// => no exception...
```

Comment: This is very ingenious hack. Hopefully this doesn't need to be done in the future.

Answer (score 6):

As you could have found out by just testing your code:

> Fatal error: Properties cannot be declared abstract in ... on line 3

No, there is not. Properties cannot be declared abstract in PHP.

However you can implement a getter/setter function abstract, this might be what you're looking for.

Properties aren't implemented (especially public properties), they just exist (or not):

```
$foo = new Foo;
$foo->publicProperty = 'Bar';
```

Answer (score 4):

PHP 7 makes it quite a bit easier for making abstract "properties". Just as above, you will make them by creating abstract functions, but with PHP 7 you can define the return type for that function, which makes things a lot easier when you're building a base class that anyone can extend.

```
<?php

abstract class FooBase {

  abstract public function FooProp(): string;
  abstract public function BarProp(): BarClass;

  public function foo() {
    return $this->FooProp();
  }

  public function bar() {
    return $this->BarProp()->name();
  }

}

class BarClass {

  public function name() {
    return 'Bar!';
  }

}

class FooClass extends FooBase {

  public function FooProp(): string {
    return 'Foo!';
  }

  public function BarProp(): BarClass {
    // This would not work:
    // return 'not working';
    // But this will!
    return new BarClass();
  }

}

$test = new FooClass();
echo $test->foo() . PHP_EOL;
echo $test->bar() . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

if tablename value will never change during the object's lifetime, following will be a simple yet safe implementation.

```
abstract class Foo_Abstract {
    abstract protected function getTablename();

    public function showTableName()
    {
        echo 'my table name is '.$this->getTablename();
    }
}

class Foo extends Foo_Abstract {
    //Foo must 'implement' getTablename()
    protected function getTablename()
    {
        return 'users';
    }
}
```

the key here is that the string value 'users' is specified and returned directly in getTablename() in child class implementation. The function mimics a "readonly" property.

This is fairly similar to a solution posted earlier on which uses an additional variable. I also like Marco's solution though it can be a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Just define the property in the base class without assigning it a (default) value.
Getting the property value without redefining it with a default value or assigning it a value will throw an Error.

```
<?php

class Base {
    protected string $name;

    public function i_am() : string {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class Wrong extends Base {
    ...
}

class Good extends Base {

    protected string $name = 'Somebody';

}

$test = new Good();
echo $test->i_am(), '<br>';  // Will show "Nobody"

$test = new Wrong();
echo $test->i_am(), '<br>';  // Will throw an Error:
                             // Error: Typed property Base::$name must not be accessed before initialization in ....


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a static property in an abstract class.

```
<?php
abstract class Foo {
    private static $bar = "1234";
    
    public static function func() {
        echo self::$bar;
    }
}


Foo::func(); // It will be printed 1234
```

Answer (score -3):

Too late to answer the question, but you may use the difference between `self` and `static` as follows

```
<?php
class A { // Base Class
    protected static $name = 'ClassA';
    public static function getSelfName() {
        return self::$name;
    }
    public static function getStaticName() {
        return static::$name;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    protected static $name = 'ClassB';
}

echo A::getSelfName(); // ClassA
echo A::getStaticName(); // ClassA

echo B::getSelfName(); // ClassA
echo B::getStaticName(); // ClassB
```

Comment: Your answer is not about the question.