# what is difference between abstract class and abstract function

Tags: php, oop, abstract-class, abstract-data-type

I know that if I create a `abstract` class, then I can't create a instance of it, and it will be just a basic class *(extending it for other classes)*. Now I want to know what is `abstract` function? *(or also is there `abstract` property?)*

I saw a function without definition in a `abstract` class *(also the function was abstract)*, so why? Something like this:

```
Abstract class test{
      Abstract function index();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An abstract class cannot be instantiated. Let's say you have:

```
Abstract class People {

}
```

You cannot do `$people = new People();`

You need to extend it to be able to instantiate it, like:

```
class Man extends People {

}

$people = new Man();
```

Regarding Abstract methods, they only contain the method signature in the abstract class and they MUST be implemented in the children classes.

```
Abstract class People {
  abstract public function getAge();
}
class Man extends People {
  public function getAge() {
    //Blah Blah
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, just can you tell me is there abstract variables?

Comment: Nope, check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634970/php-abstract-properties

Answer (score 2):

An abstract function is a function that is not yet implemented. The implementation of the abstract function has to be done in inherited classes.

A class with an abstract function has to be an abstract class.

The abstract function allow you to write algorithms in the abstract class without defining all sub-functions (declared abstract) because these sub-functions may depend on the context of the concrete inherited classes.

Answer (score 0):

From: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

> PHP 5 introduces abstract classes and methods. Classes defined as
>   abstract may not be instantiated, and any class that contains at least
>   one abstract method must also be abstract. Methods defined as abstract
>   simply declare the method's signature - they cannot define the
>   implementation.